# Python tells me my variable is not defined

Tags: python

I coded a little game giving me suggestions what to draw. I also implemented a random difficulty, it works fine for easy and medium difficulty, but when it picks the hard difficulty it gives me an error telling me that the variable is not defined. When I run it through the vscode debugger it works perfectly fine though.

```
# Importing random module
import random
# User input
difficulty = int(input("Please choose your difficultie: 1 = Easy, 2 = Medium, 3 = Hard, 4 = Random difficulty"))
# Adding the random difficulty option
if difficulty == 4:
    difficulty = random.randint(0,4)
    if difficulty == 1:
        difficult = "Easy"
    elif difficulty == 2:
        difficult = "Medium"
    elif difficulty == 3:
        difficult = "Hard"
    print("The random difficulty that has been chosen is ", difficult)
# Setting up variables
# Heroes
a = "Spiderman, "
b = "Superman, "
c = "Batman, "
# Villains
aa = "fighting the Green Goblin, "
bb = "fighting Doomsday, "
cc = "fighting The Joker, "
# Circumstances
aaa = "on top of a Skyscraper"
bbb = "in the Streets of Metropolis"
ccc = "inside The Batcave"
# Powers 
aaaa = "with weather control powers, "
bbbb = "with sound control powers, "
cccc = "without superpowers, "
# Villain Powers 
aaaaa = "who is invisible, "
bbbbb = "who has a big laser-beam, "
ccccc = "who has a remotely controlled tornado, "

# Choosing the random variables for easy difficulty
if difficulty == 1:
    final_hero = random.choice([a, b, c])
    final_villain = random.choice([aa, bb, cc])
    final_circumstance = random.choice([aaa, bbb, ccc])
    final_string_easy = final_hero + final_villain + final_circumstance
    print(final_string_easy)

# Choosing the random variables for medium difficulty
if difficulty == 2:
    final_hero = random.choice([a, b, c])
    final_villain = random.choice([aa, bb, cc])
    final_circumstance = random.choice([aaa, bbb, ccc])
    final_power = random.choice([aaaa, bbbb, cccc])
    final_string_medium = final_hero + final_power + final_villain + final_circumstance 
    print(final_string_medium)

# Choosing the random variables for hard difficulty
if difficulty == 3:
    final_hero = random.choice([a, b, c])
    final_villain = random.choice([aa, bb, cc])
    final_circumstance = random.choice([aaa, bbb, ccc])
    final_power = random.choice([aaaa, bbbb, cccc])
    final_villain_power = random.choice([aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc])
    final_string_hard = final_hero + final_power + final_villain + final_villain_power + final_circumstance
    print(final_string_hard)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never paraphrase error messages, especially if you omit the most important information.

Comment: Please always paste the exact and complete error traceback in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going to rename the variables `difficulty` as `football`, and `difficult` as `bananas` so you can spot your error more easily

```
import random
football = int(input("Please choose your difficulty: 1 = Easy, 2 = Medium, 3 = Hard, 4 = Random difficulty"))
if football == 4:
    football = random.randint(0,4)
    if football == 1:
        bananas = "Easy"
    elif football == 2:
        bananas = "Medium"
    elif football == 3:
        bananas = "Hard"
    print("The random difficulty that has been chosen is ", bananas)
```

if `football` is neither 1,2, or 3, i.e. it is either 0 or 4 then `bananas` doesn't get defined.

And hence your error..

I suspect you want to change to

```
football = random.randint(1,3)
```

Comment: Thank you really much I really appreciate the help

Comment: @RCADE always nice for an upvote or accept the answer with tick if its been helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here, you are providing options that are `1, 2, 3` yet you are using `randint` to select from `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` doesn't mesh

```
if difficulty == 4:
    difficulty = random.randint(0,4)
    if difficulty == 1:
        difficult = "Easy"
    elif difficulty == 2:
        difficult = "Medium"
    elif difficulty == 3:
        difficult = "Hard"
```

Overall I think you would benefit using `dictionaries` in this situation to remove all the repetitiveness you are facing. You could set up two dictionaries one to handle the `parts` of our final sentence. We could use keys and values that are lists. Next we can setup our `options` which will be the `keys` from `parts`. Then we can create another dictionary `mode` that will tell us which keys we will be using to select from our `parts` via slicing `option`s.

```
from random import randint, choice

parts = {
    'Heroes': ['Spiderman, ', 'Superman, ', 'Batman, '],
    'Villians': [
        'fighting the Green Goblin, ', 'fighting Doomsday, ', 'fighting the Joker, '
    ],
    'Circumstances': [
        'on top of a Skyscraper ', 'in the Streets of Metropolis ', 'inside The Batcave '
    ],
    'Powers': [
        'with weather control powers, ', 'with sound control powers, ', 'without superpowers, '   ],
    'Villian Powers': [
        'who is invisible.', 'who has a big laser-beam. ',
        'who has a remotely controlled tornado. '
    ]
}

options = list(parts.keys())

mode = {1: options[:-2], 2: options[:-1], 3: options}

diff = int(input('Choose difficulty 1 - 3 (4 == random): '))
if diff == 4:
    diff = randint(1, 3)

final_s = ''
for i in mode[diff]:
    final_s += choice(parts[i])

print(final_s)
```

> ```
> Choose difficulty 1 - 3 (4 == random): 4
> Spiderman, fighting Doomsday, inside The Batcave 
>
> Choose difficulty 1 - 3 (4 == random): 3
> Superman, fighting the Joker, inside The Batcave with weather control powers, who is invisible.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a random number from 0 to 3. When the number is 0, the variable *difficult* remains undefined because none of the if clauses matches 0. So when you get to the print, variable *difficult* still has no value.